# htaccess wildcard subdomain with subpages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, concrete5

I've managed to get wildcard subdomains active on my website. However I would like to be able to create subpages and be able to go to those subpages.

for example:
example.com == domain
test.example.com == subpage on example.com/subdomain/test
test.example.com/subtest == subpage of the subdomain , I can't get this to work.

I am using concrete5 CMS...

My current htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://www.example.com/subdomain/%1 [P,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've also tried with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://www.example.com/subdomain/%1/$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

However this always shows the content of the subdomain page and not the page below the subdomain.

---- EDIT ----

Croises gave me the answer in chat.

Here is my htaccess now which works with subpages of a wildcard subdomain (using Concrete5 CMS) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php/subdomain/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://www.example.com/subdomain/%1 [P,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /subdomain/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. This also shows the content of the subdomain page and not the content of the page below the subdomain page (Other thing is the css and javascript is not properly loaded any more).

Comment: For that, you have to use html code in the header: `<base href="http://www.example.com/">` or relative in the subdomain directory. You also can use abolute names just for css files

Comment: Base tag was already added to the header. However I still do not get the content of the page below the subdomain page with that piece of code in my htaccess.

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is. All pages and subfolders are rewritten. What is for you a page "below the subdomain" ? (example of link that is not working)

Comment: My .htaccess should give you exactly what you ask in your examples. Have you replaced your 3 first rewritecond lines by my 4 lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68948/discussion-between-jozzeh-and-croises).